# Power calculation for linear model with adjustment using unequal sample sizes

Tags: r, linear-model, sample-size

I am trying to calculate the power I have/need in a study using 2:1 ratio of samples, when the analysis will be done using a linear model with treatment as fixed effect and covariate.

I have so far looked at the pwr library in R where I can compute

```
pwr.t2n.test(n1 = n1, n2=n2, alternative = "two.sided", sig.level = 0.05, d=d)
```

but understand this is for a 2 sample t-test. Is there a similar method available for linear models with uneven sample size? How will this affect my power?

n1 and n2 have already been defined based on resources available, but I may have to advise the PI to increase this should power not be sufficient.

Comment: You can estimate power using simulations; take a look at [simr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/simr/index.html).